# Why jquery can't alert HTML tags contains body tag?

Tags: jquery

this code doen's work..

```
alert($('<body><div id="tmp">111</div></body>').find("#tmp").text());
```

but this works

```
alert($('<div><div id="tmp">111</div></div>').find("#tmp").text());
```

why is that ? thanks..

Comment: I have seen this behavior in some previous posts as well where the html parser is behaving like this when it deals with some tags like `template` etc

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the html parse is unwrapping the `body` element, so the jQuery object is having the `tmp` element as the root element not the `body` element, so your `find` method will not work you need to use `filter`

```
console.log($('<body><div id="tmp">111</div></body>').filter("#tmp").text());
```

or in this case

```
console.log($('<body><div id="tmp">111</div></body>').text());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$('.....` code isn't a selector.  It's trying to create a new DOM element from your HTML.

I'm guessing it doesn't work with a <body> tag since there can only be one body tag per page.

Comment: I think this explanation is not complete. For example it is not working even for a `p`. Try `alert($('<p><div id="tmp">111</div></p>').find("#tmp").text());`

Comment: Interesting.  Perhaps @Arun is correct above.  The difference between find and filter is whether or not it will match a root element.  Filter will match root AND child elements, while find will only match children (nested or otherwise).